# If Pyramid sessions are one-way hashed and not stored server-side, where is the data coming from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

When using the `SignedCookieSessionFactory`, the documentation states that the sha512 HMAC digest algorithm is used. As a result of this, once session data is serialised, it is signed and sent to the user's client under the `session` cookie.

There is no mention in Pyramid's documentation that sessions are also cached server-side (under this SessionFactory).

This presents a contradiction and has also led to authentication confusion when paired with `SessionAuthenticationPolicy`. If session data cannot be retrieved from the client's `session` cookie (as it is one-way hashed), how is it that the following is possible?

1. Authenticate with the application such that reading `Request.authenticated_userid` does not return None.
2. Copy the `session` cookie to the clipboard.
3. Logout by accessing a view whereby the headers from `forget(request)` are returned in the Response.
4. Replace the `session` cookie with the copied value.
5. The user is now logged back in.

I understand that simply deleting the cookie client-side is insufficient to completely invalidate the session (without blacklisting), but this then poses the following questions:

- How is it possible to remain secure with browser-scoped sessions unless *every* session cookie the user has recently been issued is somehow remembered and blacklisted/invalidated?
- Is the `session` cookie actually a key/session ID that's being used to lookup a session in memory? As it's one-way signed, surely this is the only explanation?
- Is it possible then to invalidate sessions server-side, a little more robust than just the `headers=forget(request)` pattern?

Ultimately, I imagine the answer is something along the lines of:
"Maintain server-side sessions using an include such as `pyramid_redis_sessions`"

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie contains all of the data. The session content itself is stored in the cookie, alongside an hmac signature of that content. This means that a client may view the content if they try hard enough, but they cannot change it as they cannot create trusted signatures without the server-side secret.

> How is it possible to remain secure with browser-scoped sessions unless every session cookie the user has recently been issued is somehow remembered and blacklisted/invalidated?

It depends what you're using the session for - you need to take these issues into consideration before putting data into a session object.

> Is it possible then to invalidate sessions server-side, a little more robust than just the headers=forget(request) pattern?

Not unless you store some sort of id in the session and then a server-side table of blacklisted ids. If you did this then you could write your own wrapper session-factory that opened the session, checked the id, and returned an empty one if it was blacklisted. Of course then you might just want to use a server-side session library like pyramid_redis_sessions or pyramid_beaker with one of its server-side-storage backends.